# Camera control for built-in Apple web-cams?

Tags: macos, imac, big-sur, camera

I have the 27" Retina iMac 2020 which includes an HD web-cam. It's nice but I note on Zoom/etc meetings everyone else has their face filling their camera whereas I am quite small in mine since I sit a reasonable distance away from the monitor.

I cannot find any settings or built-in applications to let me control my camera e.g. resolution, refresh, zoom... does MacOS not provide this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

[Looking around on the web](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=free+mac+app+webcam+control+zoom+in) I found [CameraController](https://github.com/Itaybre/CameraController).

As can be seen in the screenshots the CameraController app appears to be able to zoom (amongst other settings):

[image: cameracontroller]

It can be installed directly from GitHub or via Homebrew.