# How to set web camera properties on MacOS

Tags: macos, webcam

**Help I need:**

I have a shell program that *sets web camera parameters* using **v4l2-ctl** on linux,
and I need to create an equivalent program that sets those same camera parameters on MacOS (using AVFoundation)

**Background:**
I've been capturing still images from our custom webcams on linux using

- **v4l2-ctl** to *set* camera properties,
  and subsequently using
- **ffmpeg** to *capture* the images.

**I now need to port our software to *run on a Mac.***

I've learned how to configure **ffmpeg** on macOS to use **AVFoundation** filters to capture images.

But I can't seem to find the way to replace my v4l2-ctl commands with an equivalent on the Mac. I am hoping someone can provide me a URL with a working example, or write a solution below that achieves the same result as my current program.

I've done a lot of google searching, and went down a lot of iOS and other rabbit holes that are getting me close to a working example. I am not finding a *simple example* for setting camera parameters like this **on MacOS.**

Can you help me?

**My linux shell code program:**

```
#!/bin/bash
camera_id=$1
full_image_file_name=$2
# cam_props = {'brightness': 128, 'contrast': 128, 'saturation': 180,
#              # 'gain': 0,
#              'sharpness': 128, 'exposure_auto': 1,
#              'exposure_absolute': 150, 'exposure_auto_priority': 0,
#              # 'focus_auto': 0,
#              # 'focus_absolute': 30,
#              # 'zoom_absolute': 250,
#              'white_balance_temperature_auto': 0, 'white_balance_temperature': 3300}

v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c brightness=64
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c contrast=100
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c saturation=66
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c hue=0
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c white_balance_temperature_auto=0
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c gamma=500
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c white_balance_temperature=4600
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c sharpness=66
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c backlight_compensation=1
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c exposure_auto=1
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c exposure_absolute=233
v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id -c exposure_auto_priority=0

v4l2-ctl -d $camera_id --stream-mmap --stream-count=1 --stream-to=$full_image_file_name &
```

Comment: There probably is no 1:1 replacement. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425001/camera-control-for-built-in-apple-web-cams seems to be related.